# How to solve regex not working in append in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have problem in implementing regex for my field form.

User have to enter their phone number. In that field I use `input type='text'` because I want to limit the phone number user have entered to 11 digit only. That's why I'm using the `input type='text'`

```js
$("#add_number").click(function() {

  $("#phoneNumber").append(`<div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
    <label for="add_owner"> Phone Number (more)</label>
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <input class="from-control" type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" maxlength="11" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
  </div>
   `);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
  <label for="add_owner"> Phone Number</label>
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <input class="from-control" type="text" id="no_1" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" maxlength="11" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="phoneNumber"></div>

<button id="add_number">Add Number</button>
```

It only enter the first number. How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex gets mangled  - it loses the `\`

It is not recommended to have inline handlers

here we delegate to the div and clone too.

```js
const cleanPhone = function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')
};
const $phoneDiv = $("#phoneNumber")

$phoneDiv.on("input", ".phone", cleanPhone)

$("#add_number").click(function() {
  $phoneDiv.append($phoneDiv.find("div").eq(0).clone(true));
  const $phones = $phoneDiv.find(".phone");
  $phones.last()
    .val("")
    .attr("id",`no_${$phones.length}`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="phoneNumber">
  <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
    <label for="add_owner"> Phone Number</label>
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <input id="no_1" class="from-control phone" type="text" maxlength="11" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="add_number">Add Number</button>
```

Comment: it is possible not to clone the div ? because it will have different id

Comment: See update. I give it a new ID

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need to escape the backslash in the string:

```
.replace(/(\\..*)\./g,
```

```js
$("#add_number").click(function() {

  $("#phoneNumber").append(`<div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
    <label for="add_owner"> Phone Number (more)</label>
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <input class="from-control" type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/(\\..*)\./g, '$1');" maxlength="11" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
  </div>
   `);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
  <label for="add_owner"> Phone Number</label>
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <input class="from-control" type="text" id="no_1" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" maxlength="11" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="phoneNumber"></div>

<button id="add_number">Add Number</button>
```